# Why this patent is abandoned?

Tags: us20070243307

In reference to the patent: [US20070243307](https://www.google.com/patents/US20070243307)

Is the patent application abandoned or technology abandoned?  what is the reason for abandoning it?

Answer (score 1):

There are many reasons for abandoning an application, and rarely can they be known to us. Some reasons include:

- the cost of examination was too high
- the company went under before acquiring the patent
- the company discovered that the technology had already been patented
- the company decided the technology wasn't commercially viable
- the cost of a patent, if awarded, was too high
- the company thought that a patent would never be awarded
- the company decided they were philosophically/morally opposed to patents (this can happen)
- the company that created the invention was bought out, and the buyer doesn't worry about acquiring patents because they have a monopoly, or because they pursue licensing whenever possible infringement occurs
- the company decided that a patent wouldn't add value because the most important thing would be making it to market first
- the company improved on the technology, and they were only concerned with patenting the improvement, which wasn't described in the original application
- the application is part of a larger family of continuation patents, and while the particular application you're seeing is abandoned, other more important applications in the family are still alive

Unfortunately, it isn't possible to look at the history of the patent application and decipher which of these reasons applied. Business concerns drive patent strategy, and we often don't have access to what the business was thinking/experiencing when the patent was being prosecuted/examined.

---

*I am no expert, and this response is for informational purposes only and not for the purpose of providing legal advice. You should contact your attorney or legal expert to obtain advice with respect to any particular issue or problem. Laws can differ dramatically from country to country, state to state, and technology field to technology field.*

Comment: The Stack Exchange standard style seriously discourages canned "signatures" appended to all of a user's posts. I don't know enough to say if this falls under that policy.

Comment: You forgot one of the major reasons patent apps get abandoned: Changes to the law. You file under one set of rules, the Supreme Court changes the rules, and now you're stuck with a specification that won't stand up under the new rules (the Alice subject matter eligibility case comes to mind). The Federal Circuit also sometimes issues rulings that change rules mid-prosecution.

Comment: @GaryS, did you check out the application? It's for food products, so we can probably rule out changes to the law as a reason. Every now and then a case like Alice will shake things up, but I don't think that's generally a common reason.

Comment: Ok, that's hilariously correct. This is a good example of "Fundamental Attribution Error" in the patent context. I work mostly in software/high tech/telecommunications/mobile devices, and in all of those areas, changes to the law are frequently a problem (or have been since Bilski started the giant slide toward the state of confusion the law for 101 eligibility is in right now).  A good reminder for me to look at the patent application itself before commenting.  Thank you.

Comment: @GaryS, :) I primarily prosecuted in the same technology areas and didn't personally ever feel like new law was a major occurrence. Even after Bilski came out, it took a long time for people to know what it meant, and in the end, it wasn't all that hard to get software apps through (as long as the claim language wasn't overly broad). I don't still practice and can't speak to Alice--that case seems like it's different from anything else that has happened in the past. But I don't feel like Alice-esque cases are extremely common.

Answer (score 0):

The document you cite is an application, not a patent. The best way to track the status of a US patent or application is the USPTO's [Public Pair](https://portal.uspto.gov/pair/PublicPair) site. In this case select document number as the option and enter 20070243307 and you can read the entire history of the application's prosecution by clicking on the "Transaction History" tab. The application received a final rejection on 4-19-13. Final rejection's aren't necessarily final, but evidently the applicant decided to give up at that point. You can download and read the rejection by clicking on the "Image File Wrapper" tab to see the examiner's rationale.